# Reduced homology - understanding $0$-dimensional "holes" in the torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I understand that the notion of "holes" in topology is nothing formal, and that it is used for intuition based purposes, but -- given that it's supposed to be intuitive -- how can I understand why the torus (for example) has no $0$-dimensional holes (seeing as its reduced $0$-th homology group is the trivial group)?

I understand that for $S^0$, we get $\mathbb{Z}$ and that this intuitively means we have a gap between the two points. But if that's the case for $S^0$, then why don't we have at least one $0$-dimensional "hole" in the torus (say in the middle, where we can take any pair of points on the internal surface and separate it by a point -- i.e. a $0$-dimensional hole / gap)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the nature of the gap is fundamentally different, just like how the torus (or circle) has a gap that yields 1-dimensional homology but a sphere has a gap that yields 2-dimensional homology, and the nature of those gaps are fundamentally different.

The "gaps" as measured by (reduced) $0$-dimensional homology are simply the voids between path connected components (and $S^0$ being the simplest disconnected space, as it is the discrete topology on a set of two points, exemplifies this). That's fundamentally different from "loops that can't be deformed to a point" that you measure with $1$-dimensional homology, the typical examples being the circle $S^1$ and the torus $T^2$.

Comment: Actually, what happens if I have 3 toruses in a 'triangular formation'? Then, if I'm not mistaken, I have three connected components, and 3 (not 2) $0$-dimensional holes... (and the isomorphism between reduced and regular homology groups is such that it is supposed to produce 2).

Comment: @Anon One of the holes is the "sum" of the other two, so you only need two generators. The rank of the $0$-homology is the number of connected components. If you reduce it, you get that the rank is the number of "unit gaps" if you put all the connected components in a line.

Comment: Thanks! I guess we can see that it must be the case if we know that homology (and therefore 'gaps') is preserved under homeomorphism, so the triangular formation must have the same homology as the linear formation, where there are indeed two gaps.